# C++ concisely checking if item in STL container (e.g. vector)

Tags: c++, boost, stl

```
bool xInItems = std::find(items.begin(), items.end(), x) != items.end();
```

Is there a more concise way of checking if x is in items?  This seems unnecessarily verbose (repeating items three times), which makes the intent of the code a little harder to read.

For example, is there something like the following:

```
bool xInItems = boost::contains(items, x);
```

If there doesn't exist any more concise boost/stl algorithm to check if a collection contains an item, is it considered good or bad practice to use instead a helper function to enable `contains(items, x)`?

Am I using the wrong STL container?  Even a std::set would result in `bool xInItems = items.find(x) != items.end();` which still seems verbose.  Am I thinking about this the wrong way?

Comment: For `std::set`, perhaps `bool xInItems = (items.count(x) == 1);`. For the rest, `boost::find` is probably the best you can do. (There's a `count()` in both STL and boost, but they are not as efficient since they must traverse the entire range.)

Comment: Most of the relevant standard library functions are designed to operate on pairs of iterators rather than entire containers. This allows more flexibility at the cost of conciseness. You are certainly free to write your own helper functions if you want (I do), though then you've got to include their headers all over the place...

Comment: If someone could explain the multiple down votes, I'd appreciate it.  I'm still relatively new to posting on stack overflow.  Thanks

Comment: I suspect that this question is already out there. If so, that's probably the reason for the downvotes.

Comment: dlf: I like the flexibility of iterators, but the omission of additional more concise options seems unfortunate.  Maybe I'll try one of the LINQ like libraries for C++.

Comment: @JDiMatteo Personally, I'd advice against using a third party library. While it takes a bit of getting used to, the standard library functions are going to be just as fast (if not faster) than anything else you'll get out of a third party library. Adding a bunch of dependencies to non-standard libraries makes the building of your source more and more complex, and, on some systems, completely impossible.

Comment: I think you are looking for [ranges](http://www.open-std.org/Jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3350.html) (q.v.). They may (or may not) make it in to a C++ standard eventually. Meanwhile your best bet if you dislike the "pair of iterators" interface is to roll your own or use Boost.Range.

Comment: @JDiMatteo - `which makes the intent of the code a little harder to read.` You may say it looks verbose, but inventing a "shorter" method gives the C++ programmer looking at your program another function to learn.  If a C++ programmer in this day and age cannot understand `std::find` and what the parameters are, then find another programmer.

Comment: @T.C., I realized it as soon as I finished posting it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*If* your data is sorted, you can use `std::binary_search`, which returns a `bool`:

```
bool xInItems = std::binary_search(items.begin(), items.end(), x));
```

If you really need to leave the items un-sorted, but have C++11 available, you could use `std::any_of`, but it requires a predicate, so it's likely to end up at least as verbose as `std::find` (and probably more so).

Comment: std::binary_search returns a bool, so it is more concise, which is why I picked this answer over the others.  The real take away though I think is to not not worry about conciseness of iterator pairs since an iterator pair is idiomatic C++.  There is still hope that std::range will be accepted in a future standard making more concise idiomatic C++ possible.

Answer (score 7):

It's not hard to write a template function from scratch.

```
template<typename T, typename Iterator>
bool contains(Iterator it1, Iterator it2, const T & value)
{
    return std::find(it1, it2, value) != it2;
}

template<typename T, typename Container>
bool contains(const Container & c, const T & value)
{
    return contains(c.begin(), c.end(), value);
}
```

You can even provide specializations for containers that have their own `find` function so that it's not calling `std::find`.

Comment: To make the above "industrial" strength: replace `c.begin()` with `using std::begin;` on previous line, and `begin(c)` and you magically gain array support (do the same to `.end()`) (C++11).  Second, I find returning a pointer-to-element (or `optional`) is useful -- when cast to `bool` it gives the right value, and you can do `if(int* x = contains(vec, 3))` (I use an `optional<T&>`).  Add tag support to split associative from sequence containers to use associative container `find` methods instead of linear search.

Comment: The question was not how to write a templated contains function.  It was whether there already exists one in either the standard library or boost, and whether or not writing one yourself is good practice.  Still I give +1 since this is useful.

Answer (score 4):

[`any_of_equal`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/libs/algorithm/doc/html/the_boost_algorithm_library/CXX11/any_of.html) will do the task:

```
#include <boost/algorithm/cxx11/any_of.hpp>

bool xInItems = boost::algorithm::any_of_equal(items, x);
```

Answer (score 3):

From `C++20` stl containers `set`, `map` and `unordered_map` have the `contains` method:

```
bool xInItems = items.contains(x);
```

Sadly this isn't the case for all containers, so with `vector` and `list` you'll still have to write it the way you've done (or wrap into a function as in Mark's nice answer).

Answer (score 1):

One easy way to find if an element is within a set is with:

```
container.find(x) != container.end()
```

So that if you are to use a set of integers, it could be something like:

```
stl::set<int> intSet;
intSet.insert(3);
if( intSet.find(3) != intSet.end()) 
      printf("Found it!");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include "boost/range/algorithm/find.hpp"

bool xInItems = boost::find(items, x) != items.end();
```

This is as concise as should be expected given the preference towards flexible iterator usage in C++.

You should probably just stick with std::find since it is idiomatic, and hope that eventually [std::range](http://www.open-std.org/Jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3350.html) will be accepted and provide a standard more concise alternative to iterator pairs.